# Can't open a file in sublime text using bash_rc

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, sublimetext

My bash_profile function looks like:

```
function st() { /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /Users/ishan/workspace/nltk_engine/index.py;}
```

However, when I do st in terminal, it just opens up a sublime text window without opening the file. I copied the line in terminal and it is working. Its not working through bash_profile.

Comment: Which version of Sublime Text do you use? I tried with version 2.0.2 and it worked as expected: I could open a python file using a function like yours sourced from `.bash_profile`. Which is the output of `type st`? As a side comment, add functions to `.bashrc` instead, since functions not are exported to the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `st` function which is working when you type `st` is an old one which you defined interactively within `Terminal`.
If you enter:

```
type st
```

you will see that this definition is not the one you entered within your
`.bash_profile`.

To execute the definition entered within your `.bash_profile`, you have to load it within your actual shell:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

And you will be able to check that from now on your definition of your `st` function is correct with:

```
type st
```

Comment: I finally got it to work. The mistake was that there was an alias "st" in my .bashrc also. This was creating the problem. I found it by issuing the "type" command. Thanks :). Also could you tell me what things should I put in my bash_profile and what things should I put in bashrc?

Comment: @ishanJain Comments should be used to ask for clarifications on the given answer and similar stuff. Asking follow-up questions in comments doesn't work so well, it's better to [ask a new question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) in these cases. In your case it might also help to search through old questions here, on http://stackoverflow.com and on http://unix.stackexchange.com because it is highly likely that this topic has come up before.

Comment: → Ishan: good question, but please follow the Patrix comment. You'll help everyone… and yourself: better targeted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since your command is a static command, you could try an alias:

```
alias st="/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /Users/ishan/workspace/nltk_engine/index.py"
```

Comment: This won't be static. I was just trying out using a static example.